# Changing GeoServer layer name with REST API using curl

Tags: geotiff-tiff, geoserver-rest-api, curl

I have created a store via the REST API for a GeoTIFF file.
A layer is automatically created with the same name as the GeoTIFF file without the extension. I would like to change the layer name to something else.
I am using GeoServer 2.19, in a docker container, on Linux.

What I have done is the following curl command.
The layer name is **world_z7_tiled_jpg**, the workspace is **world**, and I would like to change it to **world_z7_tiled_jpg_zzz**

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT http://crazy.local:8600/geoserver/rest/layers/world:world_z7_tiled_jpg -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/xml" -d "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><layer><name>world_z7_tiled_jpg_zzz</name></layer>"
```

The command output is as follows:

```
* Connected to crazy.local port 8600 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /geoserver/rest/layers/world:world_z7_tiled_jpg HTTP/1.1
> Host: crazy.local:8600
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> accept: application/json
> content-type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 118
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 21 Feb 2024 08:53:31 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host crazy.local left intact
```

The HTTP return code is 200, which means success, I think.

I can browse the http://crazy.local:8600/geoserver/rest/layers/world:world_z7_tiled_jpg.xml in the browser to get XML info on the layer, and it looks like this:

```
<layer>
<name>world_z7_tiled_jpg</name>
<type>RASTER</type>
<defaultStyle>
<name>raster</name>
<atom:link rel="alternate" href="http://crazy.local:8600/geoserver/rest/styles/raster.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</defaultStyle>
<resource class="coverage">
<name>world:world_z7_tiled_jpg</name>
<atom:link rel="alternate" href="http://crazy.local:8600/geoserver/rest/workspaces/world/coveragestores/world_z7_4326/coverages/world_z7_tiled_jpg.xml" type="application/xml"/>
</resource>
<queryable>true</queryable>
<opaque>false</opaque>
<attribution>
<logoWidth>0</logoWidth>
<logoHeight>0</logoHeight>
</attribution>
<dateCreated>2024-02-20 13:05:18.505 UTC</dateCreated>
<dateModified>2024-02-21 08:10:24.774 UTC</dateModified>
</layer>
```

But the layer name in GeoServer stays the same, it does not change.

What am I missing?